# Python Error; 'Charmap codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 0'

Tags: python, geocoding, error, mmqgis

Please help with this error when trying to use MMQGIS plugin. [image]

Comment: I have the same problem, I think it's a character that python doesn't read like an ü, é or ñ. If i solve it i will let you know.

Comment: Thanks, I do not believe my data has those characters. In fact, when input the same data into a different spreadsheet (a shell one that I have used before for geocoding) this error does not come up and I can geocode fine. It only happens when I try inputting data into a new spreadsheet, save it as CVS UTF-8 that this error comes up. I am thinking it has an issue with the excel saving properly as a UTF-8, not the data itself.